# Error send e-mail Amazon AWS

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I use Google Service for work, my domain is ".com" I need send mail to ".com.br". The mails of ".com" arrive normal, but the ".com.br" return. I don't know where the mistake is.

In the Route S3 - type MX: Values: below

- 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
- 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
- 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
- 10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
- 10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
- 10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
- 10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM

Comment: How is your DNS configured for the two domain names? Does the .COM.BR point to the .COM domain as an A record?

Comment: My domain ".com" is an A record.

Comment: An what about how are your DSN records writen for the two domains? Does both use A records pointing to S3? Does them have MX records?

Comment: In the R3 my domain have records type: Cname, MX, A and NS

Comment: This seems a DNS configuration mistake. Your ".COM.BR" domain should be configured the same way the ".COM" is for this to work, including the `SPF` config on the `TXT` record. Take a look at this page for Google APPs: https://support.google.com/a/answer/140038?hl=pt-BR. There are some tools there that can help you.

Comment: PS.: I'm Brazilian too.